# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement - Python, MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I get an error with this code. The programming error is that not all parameters were used in the statement. I think it is regarding the update statement but i don't know what the real problem

def edit_profile():

```
username1 = username_verify.get()
password1 = password_verify.get()
full_name1 = full_name_verify.get()
faculty1 = c.get()
position1 = position_verify.get()
email1 = email_verify.get()
room_no1 = room_no_verify.get()

if full_name1 == "" and faculty1 == "" and  position1 == "" and email == "" and room_no1 == "":
     Label(text="").pack()
     time.sleep(1)
     Label(text="Please complete your profile", fg="red", width=50).place(x=250,y=380)

else:
    profile_upd = "UPDATE profile SET Faculty = %s AND Position = %s AND Email = %s AND  Room_NO = %s WHERE username =%s"
    user1 = (full_name1, faculty1, position1, email1, room_no1,username1)
    mycursor.execute(profile_upd, user1)
    mydb.commit()
    Label(text ="CHANGES SAVED SUCCESFULLY!!", fg = "green",width=50).place(x=250,y=380)
```

[the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmIRm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows that number of required parameters doesn't match with number of parameters in tuple `user1`.

In tuple `user1`, there are 6 elements but your update command has only 5 `%s`. It looks like you missed `full_name1` in update command.

The update command should be like:

```
profile_upd = "UPDATE profile SET Full_Name = %s AND Faculty = %s AND Position = %s AND Email = %s AND  Room_NO = %s WHERE username =%s"
```